# Is there some way to measure mains voltage with the ACS712 sensor?

Tags: arduino, power, sensor, voltage-measurement

Last year I went to a maker event where some guys used an [ACS712 sensor](https://www.allegromicro.com/~/media/Files/Datasheets/ACS712-Datasheet.ashx) with an Arduino to monitor the mains voltage and current to monitor the energy cost in the house.

One thing I saw there is that they were measuring the mains voltage with the ACS712 sensor (as its values had some 0.1V to 0.5V variance when I was talking to them).

I was playing at home with one of these sensors, but I couldn't find a way to measure the mains voltage with it. Is there some example or tutorial of how can I can do it?

Comment: It measures currentl, and it's isolation voltage is relatively low. Don't do anything dangerous!

Comment: Are you sure he was talking about the mains voltage changing and not just the voltage at the VIOUT pin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> One thing I saw there is that they were measuring the mains voltage with the ACS712 sensor

No, they weren't using that sensor to measure the mains *voltage*. It measures current *only*.

> (as its values had some 0.1V to 0.5V variance when I was talking to them)

That variation in the reported mains voltage does *not* mean that it was being measured using an ACS712 sensor.

> I couldn't find a way to measure the mains voltage with it

You couldn't find a way to do that, because there isn't a way to do that.

The "live side" measurement connections of the ACS712 (pins 1+2 and 3+4) are isolated from the Hall-effect sensor on the low-voltage side of the device (2.1kV RMS minimum isolation). Therefore the ACS712 cannot be used to measure the "live side" (e.g. mains) voltage.

[image: ACS712 functional diagram]

(Image from [ACS712 datasheet](https://www.allegromicro.com/~/media/Files/Datasheets/ACS712-Datasheet.ashx))

In summary: The ACS712 + Arduino system which you saw, measured the mains voltage some other way. The ACS712 was used *only* for the current measurement.